# Is a good idea to async-ize a sync method?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, async-await

In my ASP.NET Core app, at some points I'm querying a couple ADs for data. This being AD, the queries take some time to complete and the DirectoryServices API contains only synchronous calls.

Is it a good practice to try and wrap the AD sync calls as async? I think it's done like this (just an example, not the real query):

```cs
private async Task<string[]> GetUserGroupsAsync(string samAccountName)
{
    var func = new Func<string, string[]>(sam =>
    {
        var result = new List<string>();
        using (var ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "", "", ""))
        {
            var p = new UserPrincipal(ctx)
            {
                SamAccountName = sam
            };
            using (var search_obj = new PrincipalSearcher(p))
            {
                var query_result = search_obj.FindOne();
                if (query_result != null)
                {
                    var usuario = query_result as UserPrincipal;
                    var directory_entry = usuario.GetUnderlyingObject() as DirectoryEntry;
                    var grupos = usuario.GetGroups(ctx).OfType<GroupPrincipal>().ToArray();
                    if (grupos != null)
                    {
                        foreach (GroupPrincipal g in grupos)
                        {
                            result.Add(g.Name);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return result.ToArray();
    });
    var result = await Task.Run(() => func(samAccountName));
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Wrapping it in `Task` to make it "async" does nothing but add an extra layer of overhead. Do not do this. There's not a single advantage to doing it.

Comment: No, it's not. The main idea of `async/await` is thread-sharing: while you are doing work that doesn't require running thread, someone else using it. In your example you share your original thread, but take another to wait for sync operation completion.

Comment: In general, if you have an HTTP calls, it's better to make asynchronous methods, and asynchronous is a little bit contagious, so you need to make the whole chain asynchronous..

Comment: While your are using async pattern, your function is totally sync: i mean the process that runs `GetUserGroupsAsync` is waiting task's end (on line `var result = await ...`). So or your example is too simple, or in general this approach is falsy async.

Comment: @GiovanniEsposito That's just false.  The merits of this particular code aside, the method absolutely *is* asynchronous from the perspective of a caller.  The method returns basically immediately upon calling the method, and the result is accessible when available through the returned task.  That's asynchronously.  A "Falsely async" method is one that claims to be asynchronous in name or signature but that runs synchronously and just returns an already completed task, which this doesn't do.

Comment: https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/net-tasks-asyncawait-best-practices-garri-hovhannisyan - Rule 4 - `The sole purpose of Task.Run(...) is to execute CPU-bound or synchronous code in an asynchronous way.`

Comment: Required reading: [Should I expose asynchronous wrappers for synchronous methods?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/should-i-expose-asynchronous-wrappers-for-synchronous-methods/)

Answer (score 0):

> Is it a good practice

Usually not.

In a desktop app where you don't want to hold up the UI thread, then this idea can actually be a good idea. That `Task.Run` moves the work to a different thread and the UI thread can continue responding to user input while you're waiting for a response.

You tagged ASP.NET. The answer there is also "it depends". ASP.NET has a limited amount of worker threads that it's allowed to use. The benefit of asynchronous code is to allow a thread to go and work on some other request while you're waiting for a response. Thus, you can serve more requests with the same amount of available threads. It helps the overall performance of your application.

If you're calling `await GetUserGroupsAsync()`, then there is absolutely no benefit to doing what you're doing. You're freeing up the calling thread, but you've created a new thread that is going to sit locked until a response is returned. So your net thread savings is zero, and you have the additional CPU overhead of setting up the task.

If you intend on calling `GetUserGroupsAsync()` and then going out and getting other data while you wait for a response, then this can save time. It won't save threads, but just time. But you should be conscious that you are now taking up two threads for each request instead of just one, which means you can hit the ASP.NET max thread count faster, potentially hurting the overall performance of your application.

But whether you want to save time in ASP.NET, or if you want to free up the UI thread in a desktop app, I would still argue that you should not use `Task.Run` inside `GetUserGroupsAsync()`. If the caller wants to offload that waiting to another thread so it can then go get other data, then the caller can use `Task.Run`, like this:

```
var groupsTask = Task.Run(() => GetUserGroupsAsync());

// make HTTP request or get some other external data while we wait

var groups = await groupsTask;
```

Answer (score -1):

The decision on whether you should create a method for a class should depend on the answer to the question: if someone thinks of what this class represents, would he think that this class will have this functionality?

Compare this with class string and methods about string equality. Most people would think that two strings are equal if they have exactly the same characters in the same order. However, for a lot of applications, it might be handy to be able to compare two strings with case insensitivity. Instead of changing the equality method of string, a new class is created. This StringComparer class contains a lot of methods to compare strings using different definitions of equality.

If someone would say: "Okay, I've just created a class that represents several methods to compare two strings for equality". Would you expect that comparing with case insensitivity is one of the methods of this class? Of course you would!

The same should be with your class. I don't know what your class represents. However, apparently you thought, that someone who has an object of this class would be happy to "Get User Groups". He is happy that he doesn't have to know how that someone made this method for him, and that he doesn't need to know the insides of the class to be able to get the user groups.

This information hiding is an important thing of classes. It gives the creator of the class the freedom to internally change how the class works, without having to change usage of the class.

So if everyone who knows what your class represents would think: "of course getting user groups will take a considerable amount of time", and "of course, my thread will be waiting idly when getting user groups", then users of your class would expect the presence of asyn-await, to prevent idly waiting.

On the other hand, it might be that users of your class would say: "Well, I know that getting user groups will take some heavy calculations. It will take some time, but my thread will be very busy". In that case, they won't expect an async method.

Assuming that you have a non-async method to get the user groups:

```
string[] GetUserGroups(string samAccountName) {...}
```

The async method would be very simple:

```
Task<string[] GetUserGroupsAsync(string samAccountName)
{
    return Task.Run(() => GetUserGroups(samAccountName));
}
```

The only thing you would have to decide is: do the users of my class expect this method?

### Advantages and Disadvantages

Disadvantage of having a Sync and an Async method:

- People who learn about your class have to learn about more methods
- Users of your class can't decide how the async method calls the sync one, without creating an extra async method, which will only add to the confusion
- You'll have to add an extra unit test
- You'll have to maintain the async method forever.

Advantages of having an async method:

- If in future a user group would be fetched from another process, for instance a database, or an XML file, or maybe the internet, then you can internally change the class, without having to change the many, many users (after all, all your classes are very popular, aren't they :)

### Conclusion

If people look at your class, and they wouldn't even think that fetching user groups would be an async method, then don't create it.

If you think that maybe in future it could be that another process provides the user groups, then it would be wise to prepare your users about this.